# My EventBus system followup

Tags: java, thread-safety, reflection, event-handling

This question is a followup from my previous question [My EventBus system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48869/my-eventbus-system), and incorporates most points from [@rolfl's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48889/32231).

It includes, but is not limited to:

- Usage of `Collections.synchronizedSet` over manual `synchronized { }` on trivial methods.
- Minimal locking
- High performance code, but **not** going into micro-optimizations if it harms the readability of the code.

The code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Event { }
```

---

```
public interface EventBus {
    void registerListenersOfObject(final Object callbackObject);

    <T> void registerListener(final Class<T> eventClass, final Consumer<? extends T> eventListener);

    void executeEvent(final Object event);

    void removeListenersOfObject(final Object callbackObject);

    <T> void removeListener(final Class<T> eventClass, final Consumer<? extends T> eventListener);

    void removeAllListenersOfEvent(final Class<?> eventClass);

    void removeAllListeners();
}
```

---

```
public class SimpleEventBus implements EventBus {
    private final static Set<EventHandler> EMPTY_SET = new HashSet<>();
    private final static EventHandler[] EMPTY_ARRAY = new EventHandler[0];

    private final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, Set<EventHandler>> eventMapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final Class<?> eventClassConstraint;

    public SimpleEventBus() {
        this(Object.class);
    }

    public SimpleEventBus(final Class<?> eventClassConstraint) {
        this.eventClassConstraint = Objects.requireNonNull(eventClassConstraint);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerListenersOfObject(final Object callbackObject) {
        Arrays.stream(callbackObject.getClass().getMethods())
                .filter(this::isEligibleMethod)
                .forEach(method -> {
                    Class<?> eventClass = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
                    addEventHandler(eventClass, new MethodEventHandler(method, callbackObject, eventClass));
                });
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> void registerListener(final Class<T> eventClass, final Consumer<? extends T> eventListener) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass);
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventListener);
        if (eventClassConstraint.isAssignableFrom(eventClass)) {
            addEventHandler(eventClass, new ConsumerEventHandler((Consumer<Object>)eventListener));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void executeEvent(final Object event) {
        if (eventClassConstraint.isAssignableFrom(event.getClass())) {
            getCopyOfEventHandlers(event.getClass()).forEach(eventHandler -> eventHandler.invoke(event));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListenersOfObject(final Object callbackObject) {
        Arrays.stream(callbackObject.getClass().getMethods())
                .filter(this::isEligibleMethod)
                .forEach(method -> {
                    Class<?> eventClass = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
                    removeEventHandler(eventClass, new MethodEventHandler(method, callbackObject, eventClass));
                });
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> void removeListener(final Class<T> eventClass, final Consumer<? extends T> eventListener) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass);
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventListener);
        if (eventClassConstraint.isAssignableFrom(eventClass)) {
            removeEventHandler(eventClass, new ConsumerEventHandler((Consumer<Object>)eventListener));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAllListenersOfEvent(final Class<?> eventClass) {
        eventMapping.remove(Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass));
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAllListeners() {
        eventMapping.clear();
    }

    private boolean isEligibleMethod(final Method method) {
        return (method.getAnnotation(Event.class) != null
                && method.getReturnType().equals(void.class)
                && method.getParameterCount() == 1
                && eventClassConstraint.isAssignableFrom(method.getParameterTypes()[0]));
    }

    private void addEventHandler(final Class<?> eventClass, final EventHandler eventHandler) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass);
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventHandler);
        eventMapping.putIfAbsent(eventClass, Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>()));
        eventMapping.get(eventClass).add(eventHandler);
    }

    private void removeEventHandler(final Class<?> eventClass, final EventHandler eventHandler) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass);
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventHandler);
        eventMapping.getOrDefault(eventClass, EMPTY_SET).remove(eventHandler);
    }

    private Stream<EventHandler> getCopyOfEventHandlers(final Class<?> eventClass) {
        Set<EventHandler> eventHandlers = eventMapping.get(Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass));
        return (eventHandlers == null) 
                ? Stream.empty()
                : Arrays.stream(eventHandlers.toArray(EMPTY_ARRAY));
    }

    private static interface EventHandler {
        void invoke(final Object event);
    }

    private static class MethodEventHandler implements EventHandler {
        private final Method method;
        private final Object callbackObject;
        private final Class<?> eventClass;

        public MethodEventHandler(final Method method, final Object object, final Class<?> eventClass) {
            this.method = Objects.requireNonNull(method);
            this.callbackObject = Objects.requireNonNull(object);
            this.eventClass = Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass);
        }

        @Override
        public void invoke(final Object event) {
            try {
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(callbackObject, Objects.requireNonNull(event));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.method);
            hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.callbackObject);
            hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.eventClass);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final MethodEventHandler other = (MethodEventHandler)obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.method, other.method)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(this.callbackObject, other.callbackObject)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(this.eventClass, other.eventClass)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static class ConsumerEventHandler implements EventHandler {
        private final Consumer<Object> eventListener;

        public ConsumerEventHandler(final Consumer<Object> consumer) {
            this.eventListener = Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
        }

        @Override
        public void invoke(final Object event) {
            eventListener.accept(Objects.requireNonNull(event));
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 5;
            hash = 19 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.eventListener);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final ConsumerEventHandler other = (ConsumerEventHandler)obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.eventListener, other.eventListener)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The unit tests of the old version are still valid and also still pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two bugs related to type system:

Currently if all three parameter types, `registerListener`'s first, and registered `Consumer`'s and `executeEvent`'s, it works as expected.

```
@Test
public void worksAsExpected() {
    String expected = "WORKS";
    AtomicReference<String> actual = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus(String.class);
    bus.registerListener(String.class, (String s)-> {actual.set(s);});
    bus.executeEvent(expected);
    assertEquals(expected, actual.get());
}
```

In the below case I register a listener for events of type `Number` and execute and event of type `Number` but it fails to execute the handler:

```
@Test
public void shouldHaveWorkedButDoesNot() {
    Number expected = 1;
    AtomicReference<Number> actual = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus(Number.class);
    bus.registerListener(Number.class, (Number n)-> {actual.set(n);});
    bus.executeEvent(expected);
    assertEquals(expected, actual.get());
}
```

This happens because in the `getCopyOfEventHandlers` only gets the handlers registered for runtime type of the executed `event`. It should get handlers registered for the runtime type *or any super-type thereof*.

To fix this; `getCopyOfEventHandlers` should be something like:

```
private Set<EventHandler> getEventHandlersFor(final Class<?> eventClass) {
    return eventMapping.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(eventClass))
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

The second type problem is this:

When I register a handler for `Number`s and it will run for any `Number`s. Some might be `Float`s, others might be `AtomicLong`s. If I register a `Consumer<AtomicInteger>` to handle `Number`s and pass in a `Float`, which is a `Number`, I will get a runtime exception.

```
@Test
public void shouldNotCompileButDoes() {
    EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus(Number.class);
    // Not all Numbers are AtomicIntegers so this is a type error
    bus.registerListener(Number.class, 
            (AtomicInteger n)-> {System.out.println(n.get());});
    Number someNumber = 4f;
    bus.executeEvent(someNumber); // e.g. Float does not have .get()
}
```

Conversely if I register a `Consumer<Object>` to handle `Number`s and pass in any `Float`, I will always run. In fact obviously a `Consumer<Object>` can `accept` any object.

```
@Test
public void shouldCompileButDoesNot() {
    EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus(Number.class);
    // All Numbers are Objects this would work
//    bus.registerListener(Number.class, 
//            (Object o)-> {System.out.println(o);});
    Number someNumber = 4f;
    bus.executeEvent(someNumber);
}
```

To fix this; you should replace `Consumer<? extends T> eventListener` in `registerListener`s signature with `Consumer<? super T>`. In fact because the `T` only appears a parameter type in `Consumer<T>` declaration, a parameter of type `Consumer<? extends T>` should either be a type error or could be replaced by just `Consumer<?>`. I suspect latter might be the case for `removeListener`.

Answer (score 4):

While synchronization is correct now, `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>()))` is still a fairly coarse grained way to synchronize. You can replace this with `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())` to benefit from the better locking strategy of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Getting a value from a Map, or entering one if absent is made easier using lambdas in Java 8 using `Map.computeIfAbsent()` you can substitute :

```
eventMapping.putIfAbsent(eventClass, Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()));
eventMapping.get(eventClass).add(eventHandler);
```

by

```
eventMapping.computeIfAbsent(eventClass, k -> Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())).add(eventHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This greatly clarified my code. There really should have been more focus on `computeIfAbsent` (in the docs/tutorials/highlights) as this makes using multimaps a lot easier. Also I decided to obtain a set as the following: `private final static Supplier<Set<EventHandler>> CONCURRENT_SET_SUPPLIER = () -> Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());`